# PowerShell: Named parameter values

Tags: powershell

Can I define parameters so that I can do something like this?:

```
SomeFunction -Date Now
SomeFunction -Date Tomorrow
```

If I provide "Now" instead of a date value, I expect that SomeFunktion uses the current date.

Sure I could use a switch statement or something similar to check the value of the date parameter and apply the real value. But is there another way, a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use enums in powershell
[Checkout this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26436.how-to-create-and-use-enums-in-powershell.aspx#SwitchWithEnums)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use ValidateSet.

```
Function SomeFunction 
{ 
    Param( 
        [ValidateSet("Now","Tomorrow")] 
        [String] 
        $Date 
    )

    # the rest of your code...
}
```